# Removing \n \t from print output

Tags: r, text, encoding, rstudio

Quick question about how to print statements in R. When trying to print a statement to console that contains a tab or new line, R includes this in the output.

Is there any quick way to identify such formatting quirks, (that are invisble to the reader) and remove them from the output?

Example below:

```
line <- "
hello.
This
is a test."

line

[1] "\nhello.\nThis\nis a test."
```

Comment: Try `gsub('[\n\t]+', ' ', line)`

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. Possibly `cat(line)`?

Comment: Brilliant! cat(line) sovles it. Thanks

Comment: If you want to copy-paste it safely, then View(line) would work as well. You'll have to triple-click it to select all of it, followed by ctrl-c.